# Flutter TabBarView keeps calling builders

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a StatelessWidget widget for my tabBar which contains 2 statefulWidgets. The thing is that when clicking on manager to watch all my tabs(landing on my first tab as default) the tab1 widget builder keeps being called.

I have already tried this 2 approaches but they did not work:

[Multi tab / page view in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042537/multi-tab-page-view-in-flutter)

[Flutter Switching to Tab Reloads Widgets and runs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224420/flutter-switching-to-tab-reloads-widgets-and-runs-futurebuilder)

It's really annoying because in some widgets I need to make some http requests and they also kept being called as well.

```
 body:  TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Tab1Page(),
          Tab2Page(),
```

here'smy tab1 page, which is a stateFulWidget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
print("tab1: Builder");
return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
    List<SolicitudDto> listadoSolicitudesAprobadas =
        model.obtenerSolicitudesPendientes();

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildCards(context, listadoSolicitudesAprobadas)
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

This is a print capture of my debugger:

[image]

Comment: Can you share `Tab1Page` content if that is okay?

Comment: I have updated my description Dinesh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to keep the state of your screen in your TabBarView, you can use the mixin class called `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in your State class.

After that you have to override the `wantKeepAlive` method and return `true`.

I wrote a post about that here: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

**UPDATE**

You could try this way to avoid request data every time you switch tabs.

```
  //global variable at your state class

  List<SolicitudDto> listadoSolicitudesAprobadas; 


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build
  print("tab1: Builder");
  return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
         if (listadoSolicitudesAprobadas == null){
          listadoSolicitudesAprobadas =   model.obtenerSolicitudesPendientes();
        }

      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildCards(context, listadoSolicitudesAprobadas)
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

Comment: Already tried that one, it's in one of  the links as well. The thing is that when being in tab1 page, the builder keeps getting called recursively.

Comment: you have to put it inside your Tab1Page and Tab2Page

Comment: I have removed my second tab and put that into a my tab1Page. Keeps doing the same. I can not understand why is doing that I have removed all my code from page1 as well in order to discard any bugs. Also read your blog and followed the steps described.

Comment: oh yes, I saw your code, that's is because the build method is always called, I thought that you were fetching the data in the initState method

Comment: I updated my answer to avoid request data every time

Comment: Nice that did the trick! Nevertheless  I'm facing another issue I'll be posting in another question since it's kinda related but not the same thing.