# State recreates again when softkeyboard appears

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that displays information using FutureBuilder.

When I open the Textfield the soft keyboard appears and the state of that FutureBuilder gets recreated. Is there any way to avoid that unnecessary running of the build method.

Apparently,  when i use init state to call the future it works but for other functions like deleting data, it doesn't work because the future gets called only once.

this is my code

```
         class FutureBuilderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _FutureBuilderWidgetState createState() => _FutureBuilderWidgetState();
        }

        class _FutureBuilderWidgetState extends State<FutureBuilderWidget> {
          final _appBar = AppBar();

          @override 
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return FutureBuilder(
                      future: Provider.of<QuickNotesProvider>(context, listen: false)
                          .fetchAndSetNotes(),
                      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                        return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                            ? Center(
                                child: Text('loading...'),
                              )
                            : Consumer<QuickNotesProvider>(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Icon(Icons.calendar_today,
                                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.07),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 6,
                                        ),
                                        Text('Added Notes will appear here',
                                            style:
                                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          'Tap + to add a quick note',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize:
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                      0.02,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                builder: (ctx, eventData, ch) {
                                  if (eventData.quicknotes.length == 0) {
                                    return ch;
                                  } else {
                                    return Container(
                                      height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                                              _appBar.preferredSize.height -
                                              MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
                                              MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom) *
                                          0.869,
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: eventData.quicknotes.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return Container(
                                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 10, top: 7, right: 10),
                                              child: Card(
                                                elevation: 5,
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                                color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          top: 10, left: 8),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        eventData.quicknotes[index]
                                                            .quicknote,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Padding(
                                                          padding:
                                                              const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                  right: 10.0),
                                                          child: InkWell(
                                                            onTap: () {
                                                              setState(() {
                                                                eventData.deleteEvents(
                                                                    eventData
                                                                        .quicknotes[
                                                                            index]
                                                                        .id);
                                                              });
                                                            },
                                                            child: Icon(
                                                              Icons.more_horiz,
                                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ));
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                });
                      },
                    );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Seems to be the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234179/opening-keyboard-causes-stateful-widgets-to-be-re-initialized

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. When the soft keyboard appears your layout gets resized, hence rebuilt.

You can avoid resizing by setting the `resizeToAvoidBottomInsets` in the `Scaffold` ancestor of your widget, but if any rebuild occurs the problem will represent itself.

A way to handle this could be caching your `Future` results. 
I believe you can prevent the re-execution by using a [Completer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/Completer-class.html).

In your `State` create a

```
var myCompleter = Completer<YourDataDype>()
```

Then launch your future function in `initState`, but instead of returning the result, do this:

```
myCompleter.complete(yourData)
```

You can then pass `myCompleter.future` to your `FutureBuilder` and see what happens.

Personally I've never done this since I separate logic and presentation using the [BLoC pattern](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1), but it should work for your case indeed.

You should start splitting your logics too, since it'll avoid a lot of pain and improve your codebase quality!