# How to not dispose of previous widget when navigating to a new widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What I am currently doing

```
Navigator.push(context,
            RouteAnimationFadeIn(NewWidget(someValue), true));
```

RouteAnimationFadeIn:

```
class RouteAnimationFadeIn extends PageRouteBuilder {
final Widget widget;
final bool shouldMaintainState;

RouteAnimationFadeIn(this.widget, this.shouldMaintainState)
  : super(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      return widget;
    }, transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: child,
      );
    });

@override
bool get maintainState {
  return shouldMaintainState;
}
}
```

This disposes of the previous widget, which consequently disposes of data of all the form fields in it. What I want is a fragment add like the functionality of Android, so that the new widget opens on tap of the old widget so that, when I use `Navigator.pop(context);` I see the old data in it.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439047/how-to-preserve-widget-states-in-flutter-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigation), but it doesn't work.

Comment: The AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin is the way to go. How did you implement it?