# Flutter is it possible to push already initialized page without creating new state?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final myPage = new MyPage(); 

Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => myPage));
```

I need myPage not to create new state every time I push it into the MaterialPageRoute.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of buggy in master channel, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738269/8619512) you go.

```
class PersistantTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PersistantTabState createState() => _PersistantTabState();
}

class _PersistantTabState extends State<PersistantTab> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  // Setting to true will force the tab to never be disposed. This could be dangerous.
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a `key` to your widget should be enough.

```
final myPage = new MyPage(key: GlobalKey());
```

Note that your `MyPage` should accept a `Key` in the constructor in order to pass it to its `super`. You should have something like this as a constructor:

```
MyPage({Key key}): super(key:key)
```

For more information on how Keys are used to preserve Widgets I suggest [this Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d).

Comment: I do assign a global key to a new MyPage, but when I call the pop context like this:
Navigator.pop(context)
and try to push the same page again like:
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => myPage));

It creates new state =/