# Preserve state of widget in flutter even though parent widget rebuilds

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I'm trying to preserve the state of widget pages when switching between widgets using `BottomNavigationBar`. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439047/how-to-preserve-widget-states-in-flutter-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigation) that I can do this using `IndexedStack`, however, that doesn't work in my case for two reasons:

1. The `Scaffold` in which the pages are displayed gets rebuilt when switching between pages because for some, but not all, pages the `Scaffold` should be extended: `Scaffold( extendBody: _pageIndex == 1, ...)`
2. The pages should be built for the first time just when the page is opened for the first time and not right from the start

Here's a small example that shows that `IndexStack` is not working as intended because the `Scaffold` rebuilds:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _pageIndex = 1;
  List<Widget> _pages = [Text("hi"), Counter()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: _pageIndex == 1,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: IndexedStack(
        children: _pages,
        index: _pageIndex,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Goto 0',),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.business), label: 'Goto 1',),
        ],
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = index;
          });
          print("idx " + _pageIndex.toString());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo showing that the state is not preserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBxBG.gif)

This is the Counter which can be replaced by any other stateful widget:

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

//this part is not important, just to show that state is lost
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _count = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text("Count: " + _count.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _count++;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, great question! The trick is to use [KeyedSubtree](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/KeyedSubtree-class.html), and conditionally render pages depending on if they have been visited yet or not.

You could adapt your code this way to achieve your desired behavior:

```dart
class Page {
  const Page(this.subtreeKey, {required this.child});

  final GlobalKey subtreeKey;
  final Widget child;
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _pageIndex = 1;

  final _pages = [
    Page(GlobalKey(), child: Text('Hi')),
    Page(GlobalKey(), child: Counter()),
  ];

  final _builtPages = List<bool>.generate(2, (_) => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: _pageIndex == 1,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: _pages.map(
          (page) {
            return _buildPage(
              _pages.indexOf(page),
              page,
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Goto 0',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Goto 1',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = index;
          });
          print("idx " + _pageIndex.toString());
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPage(
    int tabIndex,
    Page page,
  ) {
    final isCurrentlySelected = tabIndex == _pageIndex;

    _builtPages[tabIndex] = isCurrentlySelected || _builtPages[tabIndex];

    final Widget view = KeyedSubtree(
      key: page.subtreeKey,
      child: _builtPages[tabIndex] ? page.child : Container(),
    );

    if (tabIndex == _pageIndex) {
      return view;
    } else {
      return Offstage(child: view);
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to modify this code to add more tabs, functionality, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, this is helpful! I haven't looked into keys before and that just might do the trick for me!

Comment: @witi Let me know if it works for you! If it does, do accept the answer for future readers. Otherwise, I'd be happy to continue working on it with you!