# How to preserve the state of a page

Tags: flutter, dart

How to preserve the state of a page in `PageView` or how to preserve state of widgets when used with `BottomNavigationBar` etcetera.

```
final List<Widget> _pages = const [
const Page1(key: Key("Page1"),),
const Page2(key: Key("Page2"),),
];

int _index=0;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pages[_index],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _index,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() => _index = index),
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.edit_outlined,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(                  
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.edit_outlined,
              ),),               
          ]),
    );
```

where `Page1()` and `Page2()` get Data from internet.

when moving to previous page, it is calling the API again.

Comment: What do you mean? @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve widget states in flutter, when navigating using BottomNavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439047/how-to-preserve-widget-states-in-flutter-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Indexed Stack` to preserve the data on all pages.

> Cons

All the pages (childrens) will be built regardless whether the user visits the page or not.

> Alternatives

You can use PageStorageKey