# How to store user entered qty's per PageView page when navigating to next page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several pages using PageView builder.

The pages are built using data from an API and gathered using HIVE boxes. Within each page there is a Qty box that i require the user to enter a figure but when i swipe to the next page and then back the user entered Qty is lost.

I'm new to using Flutter/Dart and wondered what's the best approach to solve such an issue.

I also have a flutter_switch within the PageView too but it if i toggle the switch ON(true) it's also the same state on each subsequent pages of my PageView builder.  Can this be solved too?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve widget states in flutter, when navigating using BottomNavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439047/how-to-preserve-widget-states-in-flutter-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigation)

Comment: It certainly, looks promising! I'll investigate and see what i can do. Many thanks!