# How to make a persistent Material 3 Navigation Bar component

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

The Flutter Material 3 NavigationBar widget is shown as persistent by the [guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/guidelines#6b9f726a-076f-4a6a-9170-2adc1b3daea0).

There are these [good examples of a simple and a more comprehensive application](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html).

I am having a hard time following the example with a button press that leads to a new page but the NavigationBar is persistent. Would it be possible to get help in understating how this is done with a simplified example? It seems like the Navigator widget and navigator keys are needed for this?

The intended behavior is that the button press will show a new widget/view with a back button in the app bar, the Navigation Bar will be unchanged and when switching between NavigationBar tabs the view of each one will not change.

Currently, the onPressed of a button in a view will result in SecondPage() being shown, but the the NavigationBar of course disappears:

```
onPressed: () {
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
  );
}
```

I am currently using the [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package, but would like to use the Material 3 NavigationBar instead.

Comment: If navigation bar is not working as expected or it doesn't have the functionality which you want then you can always create your own design and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Well i was able to piece togeher some things.
It is combination of info from these sources:

[How to preserve widget states in flutter, when navigating using BottomNavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439047/how-to-preserve-widget-states-in-flutter-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigation)

https://techblog.geekyants.com/nested-navigation-in-flutter-navigator-widget

Dart Pad - https://dartpad.dev/?id=8d85ca647f25e2b8dc430cd3eaa10b6c

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';




 GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKeyMain = GlobalKey();

   GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navItemOne =
  GlobalKey();

  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navItemTwo =
  GlobalKey();

GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navItemThree =
  GlobalKey();


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class InitialPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const InitialPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InitialPage> createState() => _InitialPageState();
}

class _InitialPageState extends State<InitialPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyHomePage()),
          );

        }, child: const Text('go'),),
          const SizedBox(height: 10,),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const PurplePage()),
          );

        }, child: const Text('log in'),),
          const SizedBox(height: 10,),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){


        }, child: const Text('sign up'),),
      ],),
    );
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Nested Navigation',

      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const InitialPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKeyMain,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

int _selectedIndex = 0;

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;





  final List<NavigationDestination> _destinations = [
    const NavigationDestination(
      icon: Icon(Icons.one_k_outlined),
      selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.one_k),
      label: 'one',
    ),
    const NavigationDestination(
      icon: Icon(Icons.two_k_outlined),
      selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.two_k),
      label: 'two',
    ),
    const NavigationDestination(

      selectedIcon: Badge(label: Text("10"),child: Icon(Icons.three_k),),
      icon: Badge(label: Text("10"),child: Icon(Icons.three_k_outlined),),
      label: 'three',
    ),
  ];

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    ScreenOne(
      key: const Key("one"),
      navigatorKey: navItemTwo,
    ),
  ScreenTwo(
  key: const Key("two"),
  navigatorKey: navItemOne,
  ),
  Container(color: Colors.green, ),

  ];
  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex, keepPage: true);



  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      _pageController.jumpToPage(_selectedIndex);
      _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex, keepPage: true);
    });
  }

  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey() {
    switch (_selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return navItemOne;
      case 1:
        return navItemTwo;
      default:
        return navItemThree;
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context);


    NavigationRailLabelType labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;

    final isSmallScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 720;

    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          final NavigatorState navigator =
          _navigatorKey().currentState!;
          if (!navigator.canPop()) {
            return true;
          }
          navigator.pop();
          return false;
        },
    child: isSmallScreen ? Scaffold(
      body:NewWidget(pageController: _pageController, pages: _pages),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        _onItemTapped(index);
      },
      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
      destinations: _destinations,),

    ) : Scaffold(
      body: Row(children: [
        NavigationRail(
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
            _onItemTapped(index);
          },
          labelType: labelType,
          destinations: const [
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.one_k_outlined),
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.one_k),
              label: Text('one'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.two_k_outlined),
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.two_k),
              label: Text('two'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              selectedIcon: Badge(label: Text("10"), child: Icon(Icons.three_k)),
              icon: Badge(label: Text("10"), child: Icon(Icons.three_k_outlined)),
              label:
              Text('three'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const VerticalDivider(thickness:
        1, width:
        1),
        Expanded(child:
        NewWidget(pageController: _pageController, pages: _pages),)

      ],),
    ));
  }
}

class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewWidget({
    super.key,
    required PageController pageController,
    required List<Widget> pages,
  }) : _pageController = pageController, _pages = pages;

  final PageController _pageController;
  final List<Widget> _pages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(

    controller: _pageController,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: _pages,
    );
  }
}




class ScreenOne extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenOne({required this.navigatorKey, required Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  @override
  State<ScreenOne> createState() => _ScreenOneState();
}

class _ScreenOneState extends State<ScreenOne> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ScreenOne> {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context);


    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final NavigatorState navigator =
        navItemThree.currentState!;
        if (!navigator.canPop()) {
          return true;
        }
        navigator.pop();
        return false;
      },
      child: Navigator(
        key: widget.navigatorKey,
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {

          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {

                      BuildContext? desiredContext0;


                      desiredContext0 = navigatorKeyMain.currentContext;



                      Navigator.of(desiredContext0!).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),),
                      );
                    }, child: const Text('purple'),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Container(color: Colors.yellow,))),
                        );
                      }, child: const Text('yellow'),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {

                      BuildContext? desiredContext;


                      desiredContext = widget.navigatorKey.currentContext;

                      Navigator.of(desiredContext!).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Container(color: Colors.pink,)),),
                      );
                    }, child: const Text('pink'),),
                  ],),
              ),
            ),);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class ScreenTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenTwo({required this.navigatorKey, required Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  @override
  State<ScreenTwo> createState() => _ScreenTwoState();
}

class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ScreenTwo>  {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;


  void _push(BuildContext context, String name) {

    BuildContext? desiredContext;

    if (name == 'Page A') {
      desiredContext = widget.navigatorKey.currentContext;

      Navigator.of(desiredContext!).push(
        CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Nested screen - Page A'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextButton(onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const PurplePage()),
                    );
                  }, child: const Text("A --> next"))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      desiredContext = navigatorKeyMain.currentContext;

      Navigator.of(desiredContext!).push(
        CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Nested screen - Page B'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextButton(onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const PurplePage()),
                    );
                  }, child: const Text("B --> next"))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }





  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context);


    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: widget.navigatorKey,
     //   initialRoute: '/',



          onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),
                body: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => _push(context, 'Page A'),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Page A',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                        ),
                      ),

                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => _push(context, 'Page B'),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Page B',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(navigatorKeyMain.currentContext!).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const InitialPage()),
                            (route) => false
                    );
                      }, child: const Text("Go back to first screen"))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }


}


class PurplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PurplePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PurplePage> createState() => _PurplePageState();
}

class _PurplePageState extends State<PurplePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(color: Colors.purple,));


  }
}
```