# Animate transition while using Stacks to preserver state between pages

Tags: flutter

How could I add transition animation when switching pages while using Stacks?

Here is example code which I've been using.

[How to use BottomNavigationBar with Navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235570/how-to-use-bottomnavigationbar-with-navigator/45992604#45992604)

Currently when you switch pages it's instant and not smooth.

Comment: Can you past the referred code in this question perhaps? This would make this question more reliable in the case of the linked post becomes being edited

Answer (score 0):

The linked implementation doesn't use any transition/animation.

Since you didn't specified which type of animation you want, I can't provide a simple solution.

However, you can easily implement your own Animation, there is lot of exemple on the official documentation : https://flutter.io/animations/

Answer (score 0):

The code in your examples relies on the `Offstage` widget. There is no way to create a transition between offstage positive and negative. That is a case for using routes instead of `Offstage` along stacks.

For route changes, animations are implemented by the framework flavor you are using(eg: MaterialApp).

Check [this tutorial](http://bizz84.github.io/2018/07/07/Multiple-Navigators-BottomNavigationBar.html) for a more detailed guide of how to use `BottomNavigationBar` along with Routes.